# Get an element of a list inside a command in SHELL script

Tags: list, shell, iteration

I would like to run a Java application with specified parameter settings, and some of the parameters will come from an iteration of a list.
This could be the proper way? Many Thanks!

```
outs="/home/user/this.vcf /home/user/that.vcf  /home/user/simulation/control.vcf"
arr=($outs)

ending=3

for ((i=1;i<=ending;i++)); do
java -Xmx32g -jar /home/user/something.jar \
-o $arr[i] \
done
```

Comment: You want to run the java command once with all the arguments or once per-argument?

Comment: 3 run with one argument, which has 3 different value. so I want to run it 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing brackets. Additionally, note that shell arrays are zero-based, so your `for` statement needs to be amended:

```
for ((i=0;i<ending;i++)); do
java -Xmx32g -jar /home/user/something.jar \
-o ${arr[i]} \
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hardcode count. Just iterate the array like this:

```
outs=( "/home/user/this.vcf" "/home/user/that.vcf" "/home/user/simulation/control.vcf" )

for word in "${outs[@]}"; do
   java -Xmx32g -jar /home/user/something.jar -o "$word"
done
```

Comment: Better would be to use an array correctly (to be able to handle files with spaces).

Comment: okay, I'll update my answer, I didn't tell something. I have 3 arguments (I didn't want to write it all to make my post (and code) simplier here, but I should have), which I have to re-parameterize 3 times, that's why I would like to solve it this way.